# Magento 2.2.1 limited categories in top menu and all categories in left sidebar

Tags: magento2

Hy!
I am trying to load in top menu only 4 subcategories and in left sidebar all categories and subcategories. I managed to load only 4 subcategories, but the same is loaded and in left sidebar. I can share the code and any help will be appreciated. Thanks! This is my code and it is located in app/code/Magiccart/Magicmenu/Block/Menu.php:

```
public function getTreeCategoriesExt($parentId) // include Magic_Label
{ 
    $categories = $this->_categoryInstance->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','magic_label','url_path'))
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 1)
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $parentId)
                    ->addIsActiveFilter()
                    ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc'); 
    $html = '';
    $counter = 0;
    $allCateg = 'Toate categoriile';
    $categoryObj = $this->categoryRepository->get($parentId);

    foreach($categories as $category)
    {
        $level = $category->getLevel();
        $childHtml = ( $this->_recursionLevel == 0 || ($level -1 < $this->_recursionLevel) ) ? $this->getTreeCategoriesExt($category->getId()) : '';
        $childClass = $childHtml ? ' hasChild parent' : '';
        $childClass .= $this->isCategoryActive($category->getId()) ? ' active' : '';
        $html .= '<li class="level' . ($level -2) . $childClass . '"><a href="' . $category->getUrl() . '"><span>' . $category->getName() . $this->getCatLabel($category) . "</span></a>\n" . $childHtml . '</li>';

        if($counter == 3 && count($categories) > 4) {
            $html .= '<li class="all-cat"><a href="' . $categoryObj->getUrl() . '"><span>' . $allCateg . '</span></a></li>';
        }

        if(++$counter > 3) break; 

    }
    if($html) $html = '<ul class="level'.($level -3).' submenu">' .$html. '</ul>';

    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made this in template/catalog/navigation/left.phtml:

first line:

```
<?php $ct = Mage::registry('current_category')->getID(); ?>
```

in the end of the file(before endif;)

```
<?php elseif( $ct == 92 || $ct == 85 || $ct == 224): ?>
<?php
$currentcategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
$subcategorys = explode(',' , $currentcategory->getChildren());


?>

<div class="block block-layered-nav">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Browse By') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
            <dt><?php echo $this->__('Category') ?></dt>
            <dd>
                <ol>
                <?php foreach($subcategorys as $cat): ?>
                     <?php $cate =  Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat); ?>
                    <li>

                        <a href="<?php echo $cate->getUrl()?>" <?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($cate)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($cate->getName()) ?>(<?php echo $cate->getProductCount() ?>) </a>                  
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ol>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but not this is the problem. A printscreen will help you to understand my problem?